# Android studio path to external sdcard

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to change the file path to work with my web application from which I upload files to my android device to an external sd card...

This code was working on android 2.2 tablet long time ago, now I have to make a change to work on tablet with Android 4.4.2, but I don't know what should I change because I'm not very much a coder myself.

I installed "FX file explorer", I put some file on my external sd card, then when I press on "file>details" for a while I get

```
PATH System/storage/sdcard1/filename
FILESYSTEM PATH /storage/sdcard1/filename
REAL PATH storage/sdcard1/filename
```

Here is my code from my app... I use Android studio

```
public static File parseMountDirectory() {
    File dir_00 = new File(URI.create("file:///storage"));
    File dir_01 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ext_sdcard");
    File dir_1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdcard1");
    File dir_2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdcard2");
    File dir_3 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return dir_01.exists() ? dir_01 : dir_00.exists() ? dir_00 : dir_1.exists() ? dir_1 : dir_2.exists() ? dir_2 : dir_3.exists() ? dir_3 : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in [Kitkat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#KITKAT) , you need permission for read/write opperations on the external storage :

Make sure to add the permissions in your `AndroidManifest`.xml like this :

```
<manifest .. >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```